# Find out what group id contains all relevant attributes in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

So lets say in this case, the group that we have is groups of animals.

Lets say I have the following tables:

```
animal_id | attribute_id | animal
----------------------------------
 1        |  1           | dog   
 1        |  4           | dog
 2        |  1           | cat
 2        |  3           | cat
 3        |  2           | fish
 3        |  5           | fish


id | attribute
------------------
 1 | four legs 
 2 | no legs
 3 | feline
 4 | canine
 5 | aquatic
```

Where the first table contains the attributes that define an animal, and the second table keeps track of what each attribute is. Now lets say that we run a query on some data and get the following result table:

```
attribute_id 
------------
     1
     4
```

This data would describe a dog, since it is the only animal_id that has both attributes 1 and 4. I want to be able to somehow get the animal_id (which in this case would be 1) based on the third table, which is essentially a table that has already been generated that contains the attributes of an animal.

EDIT

So the third table that has 1 and 4 doesn't have to be 1 and 4. It could return 2 and 5 (for fish), or 1 and 3 (cat). We can assume that it's result will always match one animal completely, but we don't know which one.

Comment: What if "dog" had a third attribute?  Would it still match 1 and 4?

Comment: If dog had another attribute, the list we get from the query would include the attribute in it. So if there is a third attribute, such as 'attribute_id = 7', the table will be 1,4,7

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
with a as (
      select 1 as attribute_id from dual union all
      select 4 as attribute_id from dual
     )
select t.animal_id, t.animal
from t join
     a
     on t.attribute_id = a.attribute_id
group by t.animal_id, t.animal
having count(*) = (select count(*) from a);
```

The above will find all animals that have those attributes *and* any others.  If you want animals that have exactly those 2 attributes:

```
with a as (
      select 1 as attribute_id from dual union all
      select 4 as attribute_id from dual
     )
select t.animal_id, t.animal
from t left join
     a
     on t.attribute_id = a.attribute_id
group by t.animal_id, t.animal
having count(*) = (select count(*) from a) and
       count(*) = count(a.attribute_id);
```

Comment: The query that has 1 and 4 won't be specific, it could easily return 2 and 5 and we'd want to know that it's referring to a fish. so the hard coding of the selects won't work

Comment: @Santi . . . You would just replace `a` with whatever the attributes are.  They are in a table, so just use the part after the `with`.

Comment: I think you want an inner join - first query returns all 3 animals even though "fish" doesn't match any criteria and "cat" only matches 1 - because of the left join, any animal with the same number of criteria as you're searching for will match. But I like the approach.